# How to check the state of signal in Qt?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

The following Win32 code checks if the event is signaled or not without waiting on it.

```
handle = CreateEvent(NULL, true, false, NULL);

bool signaled = WaitForSingleObjectEx(handle, 0, true) != WAIT_TIMEOUT;
```

What is its equivalent in Qt?

**What I am trying to accomplish:**

I have two threads a listener and a sender (which sends commands). When user clicks a button, the operations sends a series of commands but I need to verify the response for first command is received (and examine it) before I send the following command. I thought I could synchronize them around mutex or something..the receiver will signal the mutex when data is received and send can than wait on it. I am looking for convenient way in Qt to accomplish this. I am using `QTcpServer` derived class and its `listen()` method to listen on a port.

Comment: Could you describe what you're trying to accomplish?  There's really not many similarities between Qt's signals & slots mechanism vs. Win32's Event object.

Comment: @MrEricSir I updated the post with more details.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [QWaitCondition](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwaitcondition.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is none, because signals are generally a stateless concept. In Qt, a signal is simply a function call. There's no concept of a signal being "signaled". A signal that is "being signaled" is simply one whose method call hasn't returned yet - recall that signals are simply methods with some moc-generated code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about signals equivalent, I guess here is no any like this. But you can implement it by your own:

```
class A {
public:
    A() {
        QMetaObject::Connection setEmmitedConnection = connect(this, &A::signal, [&setEmmitedConnection]() {
        isSignalEmmited = true;
        disconnect(setEmmitedConnection);
    });

signals:
    void signal();

private:
    bool isSignalEmmited = false;
};
```

But I don't think you need something like this.

Comment: But there `Event`object in Win32 and MFC has CEvent class for it, so there is nothing for it in Qt?